# php - Split a date range into pieces

Tags: php

I need to split an array of date ranges in ranges by others date ranges.

For example, my start array can be:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'ID' => 2,
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-01'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-19')
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 3,
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-15'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-29')
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-01-01'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-12-31')
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 4,
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-06-15'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-07')
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 5,
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-05'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-17')
    ),
);
```

And the result I'm expected are an array with all periods with reference to ID of item, like this:

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-01-01'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-06-14'),
        'ids' => array(
            1
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-06-15'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-06-30'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 4
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-01'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-04'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 2, 4
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-05'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-07'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 2, 4, 5
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-08'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-14'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 2, 5
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-15'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-17'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 2, 3, 5
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-18'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-19'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 2, 3
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-20'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-07-29'),
        'ids' => array(
            1, 3
        )
    ),
    array(
        'from' => new DateTime('2016-07-30'),
        'to' => new DateTime('2016-12-31'),
        'ids' => array(
            1
        )
    ),
);
```

Can you help me? thanks

**UPDATE**
For now I have tried to order array by 'from' item and loop items and array of ranges. This is my code:

```
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['from'] == $b['from']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a['from'] < $b['from']) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});

$ranges = array(
    array(
        'from' => clone $items[0]['from'],
        'to' => clone $items[0]['to'],
        'ids' => array($items[0]['ID'])
    )
);
unset($items[0]);
foreach($items as $item) {
    foreach($ranges as $k => $range) {
        if (($range['from'] <= $item['from']) || ($range['to'] > $item['to'])) {
            if ($range['from'] <= $item['from']) {
                $clone = $range;
                $clone['from'] = $item['from'];
                $clone['to'] = clone $item['to'];
                $clone['ids'][] = $item['ID'];

                $ranges[$k]['to'] = clone $item['from'];
                $ranges[$k]['to']->modify('-1 day');
                $ranges[] = $clone;
            }

            if ($range['to'] > $item['to']) {
                $clone = $range;
                $clone['from'] = clone $item['to'];
                $clone['from']->modify('+1 day');
                $clone['to'] = clone $range['to'];
                $ranges[] = $clone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But result is an array with more results that I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would make this a multi-step process ... although I'm sure it could be done in one step, but the code would be - and may already be - confusing as hell (because I don't understand your code within a few seconds):

I would start with one pass where I would store all `to+1` dates and all `from` dates into an array and sort it.

Now you have your intervals. The first entry is a `from` and must match the smallest `from` date. The next date may either be a `to+1` or a `from` date. Either way, the interval is from `from` to whatever the next one is minus 1. The next interval starts from that value and goes up till the next-1 and so on.

Next step, sort the original intervals into your new intervals. (And filter out those intervals, that don't contain anything.)

Unless performance/storage is a very big concern, this will likely be good enough, and probably understandable by whomever your code will be inherited.